# How to get current post ID in functions.php

Tags: posts

This is my code in `functions.php` file.

```
function getcity(){
    global $wpdb;
    if($_POST['state']) {
        $id=$_POST['state'];
        $postid=$_POST['post_id'];
        $district = esc_html(get_post_meta($postid , 'district ', true));
        $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM districts WHERE state_id='$id'");
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $district_name=$row->district_name;
            $district_id= $row->district_id;
            ?><option value="<?php echo $district_id; ?>" <?php if($district == $district_id){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>
                <?php echo $district_name; ?>
            </option><?php
        }
    }
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getcity", "getcity");
add_action("wp_ajax_getcity", "getcity");
```

This is my code for ajax request

```
$('#state').on('change', function() {

  var state  = $('#state').val();
   var post_id = $('#post_id').val();

  $.ajax
  ({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "http://plotsup.com/plotsup_plot/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data :{'action' : 'getcity', 'state' : state, 'post_id': post_id},
    success: function(html) {

      $("#district").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#district").html(html);
    }

  });
 });
```

This my code in template file

```
 <select name="state"  id="state"  class="select-submit2" >
          <option  value="" >Select state</option>

                <?php 

                $property_state = get_post_meta($edit_id, 'state', true);
                $result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from states");
                 foreach($result as $row) {
                  $state_id=$row->state_id;
                  $state_name=$row->state_name;     
                 ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $state_id; ?>" <?php if($property_state == $state_id){ echo
 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $state_name; ?></option>
<?php  }
          ?>


            </select>    
   <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $edit_id;?>" id="post_id"/>
```

I want the current post ID in this function. How do I get that?

Comment: Did not you get post ID in `$_POST['post_id]`? You are sending it in AJAX call.

Comment: No..I did not get post id.

Comment: Can you make sure if you have set an attribute `post_id="xyz"` in the select element i.e. `'#state'` in the html code ?

Comment: No I have like this `<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $edit_id;?>" id="post_id"/>`

Comment: Can you please paste the complete code where these select elements, hidden elements are present. If you are keeping the post_id value in the hidden element, then you shouldn't use $(this), as this will point to '#state' select element.

Comment: @Subharanjan see my whole edit above..edited my ajax code and functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Here you are facing a problem because if this method is a AJAX request you don't have access to the ID of post unless you pass it on your JavaScript that given ID.

Exemple of what I'm talking about:

```
var args = {
    action: 'getcity',
    state: 'RJ',
    post_id: $('#post_id').val()
};
$.post( ajaxurl, args, function( data ) {
    // the success of the AJAX
});
```

Then you just have to retrieve that `$_POST['post_id')` on your WordPress action.

Comment: See my edit above and where do I pass post id in that code?

Comment: @KedarB I've just edited my code. Check it out.

Comment: I am getting postid there. My problem is I want to display selected option value from drop down at the time of edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the post_id from the POST values instead of the global $post.

```
function getcity(){
    global $wpdb;
    if($_POST['state']) {
        $id=$_POST['state'];
        $postid = $_POST['post_id'];
        $district = esc_html(get_post_meta($postid , 'district ', true));
        $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM districts WHERE state_id='$id'");
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $district_name=$row->district_name;
            $district_id= $row->district_id;
            ?><option value="<?php echo $district_id; ?>" <?php if($district == $district_id){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>
                <?php echo $district_name; ?>
            </option><?php
        }
    }
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getcity", "getcity");
add_action("wp_ajax_getcity", "getcity");
```

---

```
<div class="container">
    <select name="state" id="state" class="select-submit2">
        <option value="">Select state</option>
        <?php
        $property_state = get_post_meta( $edit_id, 'state', true );
        $result         = $wpdb->get_results( "select * from states" );
        foreach ( $result as $row ) {
            $state_id   = $row->state_id;
            $state_name = $row->state_name;
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $state_id; ?>" <?php if ( $property_state == $state_id ) {
                echo
                'selected="selected"';
            } ?>><?php echo $state_name; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $edit_id; ?>" class="post_id" />
</div>



$('#state').on('change', function() {

  var state  = $('#state').val();
  var post_id = $(this).siblings('.post_id').val();

  $.ajax
  ({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "http://plotsup.com/plotsup_plot/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data :{'action' : 'getcity', 'state' : state, 'post_id': post_id},
    success: function(html) {

      $("#district").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#district").html(html);
    }

  });
 });
```

Comment: I cant use div in template file

Comment: Ok. So remove that and just make the id="post_id" to class="post_id". I am suspecting that you might have duplicate ids as "post_id" in that page.

Comment: I have done that. But how Do I pass that in ajax?

Comment: `var post_id = $(this).siblings('.post_id').val();` and `data :{'action' : 'getcity', 'state' : state, 'post_id': post_id},` pass the value through AJAX. Now, in the `getcity()` you get the post_id by taking the value from `$_POST['post_id']`

Comment: No it's not working. How Do I Debug this??

Comment: Check in FireBug/Chrome Developers tool if post_id is being passed in the request. Also try to `print_r( $_POST ); exit;` in the `getcity()` method to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18216/discussion-between-subharanjan-and-kedar-b).